# Palindrome recursive function

Tags: python, list, function, recursion, palindrome

I tried to write a **recursive** function that says if a string is a palindrome, but all I get is an infinite loop and I don't know what the problem is

```
def isPalindrome(S):
    listush=list(S) #listush=['a', 'b', 'n', 'n', 'b', 'a']
    length=len(listush) #length=6
    if length==0 or length==1:
        return S, "is a palindrome!"
    elif listush[0]!=listush[-1]:
        return S, "is not a palindrome!"
    else:
        del listush[0]
        del listush[-1]
        return isPalindrome(S)

print isPalindrome("abnnba")
```

Comment: `del listush[0]` and `listush[-1]` don't delete characters from `S`, the list has nothing to do with `S` anymore. You pass on the original string into to the recursion without deleting the front and back chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things I would like to say about your code

- You can send a slice of the list, saving you the trouble of deleting
  elements.
- You don't need to convert it to a list, all the operations you need
  in finding palindrome are supported by strings.
- You are returning S in the recursive function, which would be an
     empty list(or string) because it is diminishing each recursion. In
     recursive cases, I suggest you to just return `True` or `False`

Here is an example.

```
def isPalindrome(S):
    length=len(S)
    if length < 2:
        return True
    elif S[0] != S[-1]:
        return False
    else:
        return isPalindrome(S[1:length - 1])
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```py
def ispalindrome(word):

    if len(word)<=1:
        print("Palindrome")
        return
    else:
        if word[0]!=word[-1]:
            print("Not a palindrome")
            return
        return ispalindrome(word[1:len(word)-1])

word=input("Enter word ")

ispalindrome(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, indent your code properly.

Secondly, you are calling the function again with the same argument. Call with 'listush' list from which you are deleting or delete from 'S' and recurse with S argument.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for creating a list. A python string is already an indexable sequence.

Even better, we can employ slicing and let the function return `True` and `False` instead of a tuple with text, With all of this, `isPalindrome()` becomes a one-liner:

```
def isPalindrome(S):
    return len(S) < 2 or (S[0] == S[-1] and isPalindrome(S[1:-2]))

print isPalindrome('A')
>>> True
print isPalindrome('AA')
>>> True
print isPalindrome('BAAB')
>>> True
print isPalindrome('ABAB')
>>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do an `print(listush)` you can see, that your list never changes.
The following modification of your code works:

```
def isPalindrome(testStr, orig=None):
    if orig is None:
        orig = testStr
    length = len(testStr) #length=6
    print(testStr)
    if length == 0 or length == 1:
        return orig, "is a palindrome!"
    elif testStr[0] != testStr[-1]:
       return orig, "is not a palindrome!"
    else:
        return isPalindrome(testStr[1:-1], orig)

print isPalindrome("abnnba")
```